# What is the difference between command and option in [yargs]

Tags: node.js, npm, yargs

I am using yargs for getting CLI arguments. I want to know the difference between command and option.

```
const argv = yargs
.command(
  'add',
  'Add a new note',
  {
    title: titleOptions,
    body: bodyOptions
  })
.argv;
```

**And**

```
const argv = yargs
.option('address', {
  alias: 'a',
  demand: true,
  describe: 'Address for fetching weather'
})
.help()
.alias('help', 'h')
.argv
```

Answer (score 13):

One difference is semantics: commands perform actions, options alter the way the actions are to be performed. Another important difference is that options can be assigned values. For example:

```
git commit --message "Initial commit"
```

In the example above, `commit` is the command, and `message` is the option. The `message` option has a value of "Initial commit". You can also have options without values, which are referred to as "flags".

```
git fetch --no-tags
```

Here we're using the `no-tags` flag to tell Git to fetch everything from the upstream branch but exclude tags.